# Spring Date conversion error while submiiting form

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am setting date format using the following code :

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.initDirectFieldAccess();

    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}
```

and sending the date in the same format from the jsp but getting error as:

> Failed To Convert Property Value Of Type [Java.Lang.String] To Required Type [Java.Util.Date] For Property BidDate; Nested Exception Is Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could Not Parse Date: Unparseable Date: "05/28/2017"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format is `dd/MM/yyyy` but you pass it an `MM/dd/yyyy` date (`05/28/2017`)

Answer (score 1):

From your *JSP* comes the date format different from the one specified in the class, it means your *JSP* send `05/28/2017 (MM/dd/yyyy)` and your class is waiting for the format `28/05/2017 (dd/MM/yyyy)`.

So, you can try to change this:

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

for this:

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Or in turn you can change the date format in your *JSP*